# Identification from a youtube video

Tags: identify-this-bike

I need help with identification.  I really like the style of the bike, but can't find any information about it.   Does anyone know ?

[image]

[image]

Comment: If you saw the bike in a youtube video, can't you post in it's comments to ask the author?

Comment: I asked him, never responded, i guess he never saw the comments

Comment: Do consider posting the youtube link.

Comment: I recognize the channel as [Alex French Guy Cooking](https://www.youtube.com/user/FrenchGuyCooking/videos) but I don't know which video.

Comment: Yes, it's him , i didn't thought posting the link of the videos gave additional infos

Comment: @user3224017 It will potentially allow people to see the bike from different angles, which could be helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think its strikingly similar to a **VanMoof Electric S** or an **S2** bike.

- Note the panel in the forward part of the top tube but aft of the headtube.
- Crankset and Mudguards are very similar to the VanMoof pictured
- The name "alex" is some aftermarket decal and a distraction.
- Its likely a European bike or design, because it has a front dynamo hub to make electricity while riding, and permanently fixed lights.

Simple differences:

- The grey bracket on the seat tube is a holder for a kids seat.  Personally I'd recommend a different style, but that's my preference.
- That front basket must be some kind of optional add-on made for the bike.  It clearly fastens to the elongated "prow-tube" (?) and relocates or duplicates the on-board integrated front light.

[image: https://cdn.vox-cdn.com/thumbor/wjQ7iuVL3z0rtu-Plimyyu-ljUc=/0x0:2500x1667/1200x0/filters:focal(0x0:2500x1667):no_upscale()/cdn.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_asset/file/6543947/vanmoof-electric-bike-01790.0.jpg]

They're pretty pricey electric bikes overall, with a strong hipster appeal.

Further reading https://www.theverge.com/2018/5/29/17404180/vanmoof-s2-x2-price-date-specs

Comment: The basket appears to be the 'waitress set' listed in the accessories section of the VanMoof website

Comment: Mudguards are Curana C-LITE. They are ubiquitous on up market city bikes and fixies.

Comment: Yes , that's exactly that , thank you !